# Determine jQuery.draggable sweetspot

Tags: jquery, draggable, droppable

I have this windows-like window with a title-bar as a handler, and when I drop it on a set of elements, it will snap to that element.
However when more than 50% of the dragged window is outside the droppable element it will snap to the element that is underneath the largest portion of the dragged window.

I don't have an example I can post now, but I hope you know what I mean.

Any ideas on how to get the position of the mouse or handler and let that be the drop location, rather than the whole window I'm dragging? (without using `.mousemove()`)

Comment: The standard formula for the center of a convex polygon is an average of the points of the vertex -- easy for a rectangle, I'd bet they used that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should look at the snapMode and snapTolerance in the documentation, I think it will help you

http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Draggable#option-snapMode

http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Draggable#option-snapTolerance

Comment: The droppable still wont understand where I want to drop my draggable, I'm looking for somehing like snapMode: 'upperleft' so the upperleft corner is always the place that looks underneath which element it should 'snap' to, I don't really use the snap to edges, I actually appendTo the element that is dragged to the droppable..

Comment: Look at this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8126285/jquery-nestedsortable-block-the-drag-of-an-element-to-the-top-level , the nested sortable maybe  will help you

Comment: Ok, hold your horses, I found it:

I need to give the droppable the:

    tolerance: 'pointer'

attribute.

Fixed it