# NestedSortable: isAllowed() does not work when connectWith() is used

Tags: nested-sortable

I am using nestedSortable with a isAllowed condiction:

```
    $('ol.nestedSortable').nestedSortable({
        forcePlaceholderSize: true,
        handle: 'div',
        helper: 'clone',
        connectWith: 'ol.item-tree', //!
        items: 'li',
        opacity: .6,
        placeholder: 'placeholder',
        revert: 250,
        tabSize: 25,
        tolerance: 'pointer',
        toleranceElement: '> div',
        maxLevels: 0,

        isTree: true,
        expandOnHover: 700,
        startCollapsed: true,

        isAllowed: function (item, parent) {
            if (!parent.attr('accepttypes')) {
                return true;
            }

            if (parent.attr('accepttypes') == "none") {
                return false;
            }

            if (parent.attr('accepttypes').indexOf(item.attr('type')) >= 0) {
                return true;
            }

            return false;
        },
        ....
```

but isAllowed only works within a single tree. When being dragged into another tree ( defined by connectWith, a li can be dropped to the tree's root (and some other places) even if the condition is not met. And then I realized that a li can be dragged to it's own tree's root without meeting the condition as well.

Answer (score 1):

I found no question and answer here and then after an hour, I solved it myself.

The answer is that, when dragged to the root of a tree ( or a second tree), isAllowed: function (item, parent) will set parent as null, rather than the ol or li that you think should be the root! So simplely adding a check can resolve this problem.

Here is the solution:

```
        isAllowed: function (item, parent) {
            if (parent == null) {
                return false; //Or do something else.
            }

            ...
```

Moreover, connectWith and isAllowed cost me a single day when we started to use nestedSortable, hopefully this can be a sample of how to use them as well.